# whenever I save a text file as .php it's disappearing

Tags: php, windows, file, hidden, text-editor

I've been searching here and all over and couldn't find anything related.
The situation is this - I get into a simple text editor > write some code > save as ('all files') say post.php > file appears for a split second and then vanishes completley.

I've tried modifing authorizations and also to reveal hidden files from folder options and it didn't help.

Anything, anyone? :)
Thanks alot!

P.S. 
I've tried saving the file from another PC and then sent it to my email, but when I've tried downloading it - it failed.

Comment: Can you save the same file as post.txt?
If that's the case, what happens if you rename the file to post.php?

Comment: I've voted to close until we get more information.  Pics more description please.